# bash script to curl all urls in array

Tags: bash, parsing, curl, jq

i have an array of urls like (coming out of a jq call):

```
["https://example.com/text.txt", "https://example.com/text2.txt", "https://example.com/text3.txt"]
```

how to loop through this and curl each of these urls into the current folder?

edit:

```
for link in $(jq -c 'xxxx' file.txt); do
    echo "$link"
  done
```

Comment: assuming the returned value to links is a bash array you can simply iterate over it using **for link in ${links[@]}**. if not you can use **readarray** to split a string into an array by a separator

Comment: not working.. `syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r'' ..... line 6: `  for link in "${links[@]}"; do`

Comment: It looks like you have nasty, Windows-y, Carriage Returns in your file. `bash` expects lines to end with linefeeds. Try `cat -vet YOURSCRIPT` to see them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling a command, to get the list of links, you can simply iterate over the result of the command, something like:

```sh
for link in "$(jq <args...>)"; do
    # do something here
done
```

or:

```sh
while read -r link; do
    # do something here
done <<< $(jq <args...>)
```

Comment: not working `line 5: syntax error near unexpected token $'do\r''`

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. check if you are using bash and/or try my second method

Comment: btw, it's a good idea to quote the array in a for loop (I edited my example).

Answer (score 0):

As the JSON array is "coming out of a jq call", just have jq output it as a list of raw-text urls using `.[]` and the `-r` option, then pipe that list into `xargs` using `curl`.

```sh
jq -r '… | .[]' | xargs -I{} curl -O {}
```

If you cannot modify the original jq filter, insert another call to jq to your pipe:

```
… | jq -r '.[]' | xargs -I{} curl -O {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the end of your jq code, and pipe to `sh` to run it:

```
jq -r '[ "curl", .[] ] | @sh' | sh
```

- The `@sh` filter correctly escapes output for a shell
- A single shell command is an array/list, delimited by whitespace: `cmd opts ... args ...`, and curl can take multiple URL arguments.
- So in jq, you can prepend the `curl` command (and any options) as extra elements in the array, and filter through `@sh`, to generate a correctly quoted shell command.
- Note that the order of elements in a JSON array is preserved, which is what we want - `curl` first.
- You can run jq without the pipe, to inspect what will be executed:

For example:

```
echo '["https://example.com/text.txt", "https://example.com/text2.txt", "https://example.com/text3.txt"]' |
jq -r '[ "curl", .[] ] | @sh'
```

Should produce:

```
'curl' 'https://example.com/text.txt' 'https://example.com/text2.txt' 'https://example.com/text3.txt'
```

The quotes around `curl` are fine. This  output can be piped (in the shell) to `sh`, to execute.

Answer (score 0):

This will create 3 files in the current directory:

```
echo '["https://example.com/text.txt", "https://example.com/text2.txt", "https://example.com/text3.txt"]' | jq '.[]' | xargs -n 1 curl -O
```